# In Node-RED/Watson IoT my Java device client keeps switching between connect and disconnect

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, node-red, watson-iot

The problem I am having is when I ran my local device client in a Java IDE the Watson IoT Service received my events fine.

But when I insert a Watson IoT input node in node red and a debug node to view the message in Node-RED my Java IDE keeps showing the error message:

`connection lost: reason code 32109  cause: EOF exception`

Then reconnects and then disconnects keeps doing this, also no message is shown in the debug panel.

I know EOF means End of file exception but displays the data in my file in Watson IoT just fine so do not know what the difference is in Node-RED.

Also I am able to send a timestamp in Node-RED to my devices in Watson IoT using the Watson IoT output node.

Comment: The usual reason for a device flip flopping between connected/disconnected is a second device with the same clientid. ClientIDs need to be globally unique for any given broker.

Comment: thanks for replying all my device ids (i think this is the same as client id) are unique but i researched and found out that it may be as you are saying client id being reused but it may be down to running the device client not properly closing as i tend to press the red square button to exit the code and that may not shut the client properly and i am re running the same client. i am going to have a look how you can close any running client connections.

Comment: UPDATE :First i created a new device client using the documentation and my old code mixed so there is nothing wrong with my client device. Second I connected and disconnected at will when i was just connecting to watson iot the problem occurs when i create the node red watson iot input node and add the configuration for my device client it must be configuration i am passing but there are only two option connect by device or gateway i have tried both but no luck yet

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61504682/edit) the question to add details

Comment: Solution: The problem was i was using the wrong node i was using the watson iot node instead of the ibm iot node

Comment: If you have a solution add a real answer, which you can mark as accepted and others will be able to find it.

Comment: Oh ok thanks first time posting in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Solution: i was using the wrong node in node red it was a ibm iot node i was supposed to use not a watson iot node